# how to install nvidea drivers of my alienware m14x , ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, alienware

I bought a new alienware m14x r2 , and I'm having some problems with the drivers !
the problem is the graphics drivers : when I play a video in youtube I can only get 720 HD ! in my mac I can get way more than this !
so is there any solution for my problem? 
Thanks is advance

Comment: I would suggest you make two separate questions for this.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu Nvidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer Nvidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.